# trying to understand onPageScrolled

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have a `viewpager` with  a `VideoView`.

So I want when I scroll the current page that video to pause. This stuff I am doing at `onPageScrolled` but I have encountered a problem because this method is called multiple times.

I have searched on android official documentation but i haven't found nothing.

viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){

```
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {


    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) viewPager.findViewWithTag("videoView"+position);
    if(videoView!=null){
        Log.d(TAG,"onPageScrolled "+position);
        videoView.pause();
    }

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onPageSelected "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    View view = (View) viewPager.findViewWithTag("view" + position);
    if(view!=null) {

        //ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fullScreenVideoThumbnail);
        //thumbnail.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Log.d(TAG,"onPageSelected Position: "+position);
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.fullScreenVideoFullVideo);
        videoView.bringToFront();
        videoView.start();
    }



}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onPageScrollStateChanged",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can have another check along with videoView!=null, to check if the video is already paused. If it is then do nothing and if it isn't, pause it. This will ensure no matter how many times that method calls it only pauses the video once

Comment: thanks. you gave me an idea. instead of what you said i'm using **onPageSelected position** saving as a variable and then compare it within the **onPageScrolled**

Comment: don't you need the video to pause on a scroll though? If you use onPageSelected everytime the page is selected it will pause the video. But i think i might've misunderstood your post, it would help to be more clear next time. Your welcome anyways